# C# get project references that are projects

Tags: c#, runtime, system.reflection

Is it possible to get all the project references that my project has? So for instance, my Project A has a reference to Project B and Project C. I don't want to get references for everything like libraries and such, just other projects in my solution. I need it in code so I can save it in a database.

Comment: Just for clarification. Do you need something for a runtime usage or more something like a VS plugin?

Comment: I need to show it in runtime.

Comment: In this case, your accepted solution and the other VB snippet won't work, because they are bound to Visual Studio. At runtime .NET makes no difference between your own Library and an external.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use classes from [`Microsoft.Build.Evaluation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation?view=netframework-4.8) to help with this.

Specifically, the `ProjectCollection` class. To use this you need to add the following references to your project:

- `Microsoft.Build`
- `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core`

(When adding these via the *Reference Manager*, look in Assemblies -> Extensions, otherwise you might reference an old version which doesn't work with newer project files.)

Then you can write code such as the following to iterate through all the project references:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var projectCollection = new ProjectCollection();
            var projFile          = @"E:\Test\CS7\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj";
            var project           = projectCollection.LoadProject(projFile);
            var projectReferences = project.GetItems("ProjectReference");

            foreach (var projectReference in projectReferences)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(projectReference.EvaluatedInclude);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a code analyzer to me,

If you start a new 'Stand-Alone Code Analysis tool' project a pretty complete sample project will be generated for you. 
I'm not quite sure how far it goes, but you end up with a `SolutionLoader` object.

Iterate over the `loader.Solution.Projects` to get all projects in your solution. 
Each `Project` has a `ProjectId` and a property `AllProjectReferences` (which includes references outside your project).

Filtering these by projectId's which are included in your solution shoulg get you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

You can just right click on each project and navigate to the BuildDependencies > ProjectDependencies.

Assuming you're not trying to write an external project analyzer/dependency graph creator.

Update as per comment:
If you are doing a static code analyzer (go through the files in the solution) you can iterate the .csproj files and extract the parts like the following:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\xyz.Service.Client\xyz.Service.Client.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\xyz.Service.Interface\xyz.Service.Interface.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\xyz.Web.Interface\xyz.Web.Interface.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

You can map it to a desired dto structure and save it as you wish. Here is some code that might ease the solution:

```
XNamespace msbuild = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";
XDocument projDefinition = XDocument.Load(fullProjectPath);
IEnumerable<string> references = projDefinition
    .Element(msbuild + "Project")
    .Elements(msbuild + "ItemGroup")
    .Elements(msbuild + "Reference")
    .Select(refElem => refElem.Value);
foreach (string reference in references)
{
    Console.WriteLine(reference);
}
```

Comment: I was more looking for a code solution so I can save it in a database. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: But like a static code analyzer or some sort of disassembler?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no "IsPartOfSolution"-Flag you can check.

But it is relatively easy to condense the full list down:

```
IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => a.FullName.Contains("SolutionName"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this code in vb.net that could fit your requirements:

```
Private Sub GetProjectReferences()
    Dim lines = New List(Of String)
    Dim path = "..\..\TestApp.vbproj"
    For Each line In File.ReadAllLines(path)
        If line.Contains("<ProjectReference") Then
            Dim projNameWithExtension = line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
            Dim projName = projNameWithExtension.Substring(0, projNameWithExtension.IndexOf(".vbproj"))
            lines.Add(projName)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If you translate it to c# (function and variable definitions, and .vbproj to .csproj) it could be of some use